# mySQL: Select rows if text column contains an item on a blacklist

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that can select all posts from my database that contain a blacklisted tag unless the post contains a whitelisted tag. Tags are stored in a text column (i.e., `" tag1 tag2 tag3 "`).

Take for example this pseudo code:

```
let whitelist = ['tag1', 'tag3', 'tag5'];
let blacklist = ['tag2', 'tag4', 'tag6'];

connection.query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `tags` CONTAINS BLACKLIST TAG AND NOT WHITELIST TAG;', function (err, results) {
    // Returns all posts that have a blacklisted tag unless the post contains a tag on the whitelist
});
```

Is it possible to generate a query using the contents of whitelist and blacklist to select posts that contain a blacklisted tag unless they contain a whitelisted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to properly normalise your `tags` and not have a list of space-separated values. If you're stuck with that format though, you can use regex to look for one of the values in each array inside the list of tags. You can make the regex from the `whitelist` and `blacklist` arrays using:

```
whitelist_regex = ' ' + whitelist.join(' | ') + ' ';
blacklist_regex = ' ' + blacklist.join(' | ') + ' ';
```

Then your query becomes

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `tags` RLIKE ? AND `tags` NOT RLIKE ?', 
                 [ blacklist_regex, whitelist_regex ],
                 function (err, results) {
                      // ...
                 });
```

**Update**

If the tags field looks like a series of space-separated values of the form `tagtype:tag`, you can change the two regexes to match that format:

```
whitelist_regex = ':' + whitelist.join(' |:') + ' ';
blacklist_regex = ':' + blacklist.join(' |:') + ' ';
```

Comment: Unfortunately because of the software I am using I must keep the tags in the current format.

Is the regex doing an exact match of the tags? The way tags must be stored in the text field have a tag type prepended to them while the blacklist cannot have this. For example, tags in the in the database look like `artist:somebody` but in the blacklist `somebody`. Is there a way to ignore the `:` and the characters before it when matching tags?

Comment: @BoneJones yes - the regex is doing an exact match of the tags, but that can be changed. Do all the values in `tags` look like `tagtype:tag`?

Comment: @BoneJones see my edit. That will work for tags stored as `tagtype:tag`. SQL demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=752645770af37e415ad4f53c4385aad8

Comment: Works now, however, Is there any way to speed up the process. The posts table is about 450,000 rows long and it takes on average 12 minutes to complete this query. This is drastically longer than for example when I use the software to search for images by tag.

Comment: @BoneJones unfortunately the problem is that you can't use an index on tags because of the regex comparison (which is also slow in and of itself). If you can I would really recommend splitting out a separate tags table with `(id, post_id, tagtype, tag)` columns, then you can compare the tags directly and potentially use an index on them.